# Problema con diccionario vacío en Python

Tags: python, archivo, bucle-for, diccionarios

Gente, estoy tratando de hacer el siguiente ejercicio:

> ***Ejercicio 2: Escribir un programa que clasifica cada mensaje de correo dependiendo del día de la semana en que se recibió. Para hacer
>   esto busca las líneas que comienzan con “From”, después busca por la
>   tercer palabra y mantén un contador para cada uno de los días de la
>   semana. Al final del programa imprime los contenidos de tu diccionario
>   (el orden no importa).**
>
> **Línea de ejemplo:**
>
> From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008
>
> **Ejemplo de ejecución:**
>
> python dow.py
>
> Ingresa un nombre de archivo: mbox-short.txt
>
> {'Fri': 20, 'Thu': 6, 'Sat': 1}

La cuestión es que escribí el siguiente código:

```
def file_reader():
    """Lee las líneas de un archivo en búsqueda de días
de la semana, para luego generar un histograma con la cantidad de veces que
se repiten usando un diccionario."""
    archive = "mbox-short.txt"
    fhandler = open(archive)
    words_container = []
    for line in fhandler:
        if line.startswith("From "):
            splitter = line.split()
            words_container.append(splitter)
        else:
            continue
    mail_day = {}
    for word in words_container:
        if word == "Mon" or word == "Tue" or word == "Wed" or word == "Thu" or word == "Fri" or word == "Sat" or word == "Sun":
            mail_day[word] = mail_day.get(word, 0) + 1
        else:
            continue
    print(mail_day)


file_reader()
```

...pero al momento de ejecutarse el print(mail_day), el diccionario sale vacío. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que haces:

```
words_container.append(splitter)
```

por lo que la lista tiene como cada item la salida completa de `str.split`, en este caso una lista como:

```
['From', 'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za', 'Sat', 'Jan', '5', '09:14:16', '2008']
```

esto hace que el condicional `if word == "Mon" or word == "Tue" ...` nunca sea cierto.Debes indizar sobre el tercer elemento de la lista para obtener el día:

```
words_container.append(splitter[2])
```

Un par de observaciones:

- Es siempre buena practica cerrar de forma explícita un archivo cuando se termina con el, el GC lo cerrará tarde o temprano, pero no es una tarea que debamos delegar al recolector de basura por lo general. Usa el método `close` o mejor, el administrador de contexto con `with` que cerrará el archivo incluso si hay excepciones de por medio.
- La lista realmente es innecesaria.
- Puede limitar el número de particiones de `split`, no necesitas parsear más allá del día de la semana.

---

```
def file_reader():
    """Lee las líneas de un archivo en búsqueda de días
    de la semana, para luego generar un histograma con la cantidad de veces que
    se repiten usando un diccionario."""

    archivo = input("Ingresa un nombre de archivo: ")
    mail_day = {}

    with open(archivo) as fhandler:
        for line in fhandler:
            if line.startswith("From "):
                word  = line.split(maxsplit=3)[2] 
                if word in ("Mon", "Tue", "Wed" , "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"):
                    mail_day[word] = mail_day.get(word, 0) + 1
    print(mail_day)


file_reader()
```